# What gets pass in the body of a POST call when sending a data class in kotlin Android Studio?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, retrofit

I have this post request using retrofit in kotlin Android Studio

```
@POST("/registerUser.php")
    suspend fun createPost(
        @Body user: User
    ):Response<User>
```

The data class User is

```
data class User(
    //val id: Int?,
    val username:String?,
    val address: String?
)
```

If I check the content of user

```
val user = User("Kilo", "Old")
Log.d("TAG", "$user")
RetrofitInstance.api.createPost(user) <----- This makes the @POST
```

I get

```
User(username=Kilo, address=Old)
```

So what do I receive on the server side? Does it convert everything to json or does it just pass
User(username=Kilo, address=Old)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a User object using Retrofit's @Body annotation in a POST request, Retrofit should automatically serialize the User object into a JSON before sending it to the server. In your case, the serialized JSON representation of the User object will look something like this:

```
{
    "username": "Kilo",
    "address": "Old"
}
```

On the server side, you should receive this JSON data as the request body. You can then parse this JSON data to access the individual fields, such as `username` and `address`. The server should automatically be set up to handle incoming JSON data and deserialize it.